# C++11 move semantics and Microsoft Visual C++ compiling optimization

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11, visual-studio-2012, move-semantics

Let's consider following class template of custom array in Microsoft Visual C++ (Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 RC, version 11.0.50522.1 RCREL).

```
/*C++11 switch-on*/

#include <iostream>

template <typename element, unsigned int size>
class array
{
    private:
        element data[size];
    public:
        array(){}
        ~array(){}
        array(const array & other)(){}
        element & operator [](unsigned int i)
        {
            if(i<size)
                return data[i];
            else
                throw std::runtime_error("Out of boundary");
        }
}
```

Note that constructor, destructor and copy constructor are defined to do nothing. A trivial printing function is defined as following

```
/*printing*/

template <typename element, unsigned int size>
void print(test::array<element, size> & content)
{
    unsigned int i=0;
    for(std::cout<<"["<<content[i++];i<size;std::cout<<content[i++])
        std::cout<<",";
    std::cout<<"]"<<std::endl;
}
```

When program runs the following main

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    array<int, 3> a;

    /* uniform initialization is not supported yet
     * so we bother iterating to assign to initialize
     * a to [1,2,3]
    */

    for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
        a[i]=i+1;

    /*copy*/
    auto b=a;

    /*move*/
    auto c=std::move(a);

    /*change in a*/
    a[0]=0;

    print<int, 3>(a);
    print<int, 3>(b);
    print<int, 3>(c);

    return 0;
}
```

the outputs turn out to be different depending on compiling optimization. Particularly, if I compile and run

- with /Od switch on

  *a*=[0,2,3]

  *b*=[1470797225,-2,9185596]

  *c*=[0,2620008,9186761]
- with /O1, /O2 or /Ox switch on

  *a*=[0,2,3]

  *b*=[0,2,3]

  *c*=[0,2,3]

Now I understand that

- with /Od switch on

  - *b* is different from *a* because copy constructor does nothing when called
  - *c* is different from *a* because copy constructor does nothing when called. But according to move semantic, change of element in array data in *a* also reflects to *c*. So a[0]==c[0]==0.

But I don't understand why *a*, *b* and *c* are all equal with optimization switch on. I might think that Microsoft C++ compiler replaces copy constructor that does nothing with one that does move, but I'm just not sure about it.

Comment: Pretty sure the VS2012 RC is version 17 or 18 of the compiler, not 11.

Comment: Anyway, you have undefined behavior, since you read from a variable you never wrote to.  Anything the compiler does is correct.

Comment: a[0]=0 is UB. You moved the instance 'a' to 'c'. (And any access to 'a' after the move actually)

I was also able to reproduce that behavior with VS2010 so I'm going to re-tag this as it's not specific to VS2012.

Comment: @BenVoigt What do you mean by reading a variable that is never written to? The point is that *a*, *b* and *c* are equal in the first place, which is not supposed to be since copy constructor does nothing.

Comment: @LeSnip3R: It's not `a[0] = 0;` that's UB, it's `print` reading members that have never been initialized.

Comment: @Yang: You have fallen victim to one of the logical fallacies.  If I have `int x, y;` and set `x = y;`, then `x` and `y` are certainly equal.  If I don't set `x = y;`, they *might* be equal or they might not, depending on what values they had before I didn't do the assignment.

Comment: @LeSnip3R Semantically, it's UB. But in VS, it seems to me that the move semantic is realized through alias of name of variable.

Comment: @BenVoigt he actually initializes his elements, so I'm not sure what you mean. He actually has a comment there explaining how he initializes the elements, so where does that un-initialized elements read come from ?

Comment: @Yang: BTW, to get the compiler version, open the visual studio command prompt and type `cl`.  Version of the editor really doesn't affect anything.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Section `[conv.lval]` of the Standard decrees that:

> A glvalue of a non-function, non-array type `T` can be converted to a prvalue.  If `T` is an incomplete type, a program that necessitates this conversion is ill-formed. If the object to which the glvalue refers is not an object of type `T` and is not an object of a type derived from `T`, **or if the object is uninitialized, a program that necessitates this conversion has undefined behavior**. If `T` is a non-class type, the type of the prvalue is the cv-unqualified version of `T`. Otherwise, the type of the prvalue is `T`.

Inside `print`, the expression `cout << content[i++]` uses an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion.  When you call `print(b)` or `print(c)`, the conversion takes place on an object that has never been initialized, so you have undefined behavior.

Trying to characterize undefined behavior is an exercise in futility.

---

NOTE: Objects `b` and `c` are initialized by the copy constructor.  The copy constructor does not initialize the subobject `b.content` or `c.content`, meaning that these arrays, and all their member elements, are formally *uninitialized*.

The code doesn't actually move from `a` when initializing `c`.  `std::move` creates an rvalue-reference, which makes moving possible, but there is no matching constructor accepting an rvalue-reference, so the copy constructor is used, `a` is copied and not moved.

Comment: Ok. So b.content and c.content just happen to be with the same value [1,2,3] in release version of the program, while all including a.content turns out shuffled in debug. Hmm...

Comment: Hmm... I think that trying to characterize semantically undefined behavior helps me to develop logics independent of linguistics. It occurs to me and perhaps all Chinese programmers who don't program and reason in English. It makes us different and "dangerous exploit to the western logical system", though we didn't mean it at all ;-)

Comment: There is also an additional difficulty for Chinese programmers: writing code in the Latin Alphabet is very difficult for a person who is used to another set of symbols.

Comment: I'm not sure how the culture you come from reflects on compiler optimization but that's certainly one way of looking at it :p

Comment: @Yang: All that tells me is that you aren't translating the phrase "undefined behavior" correctly.  It doesn't mean "undocumented".  It means it may not be consistent or have any pattern to it at all.

Comment: @LajosArpad Well, it's not just about symbols.

Comment: @BenVoigt I got you Ben. But I think that the evaluation of an expression in programming language, in this case x[0]=0, can be either deterministic or non-deterministic (I have had a course about semantics and types here in university in Denmark where Bjarn Stroustrup is from, the teacher uses "deterministic/non-deterministic" massively in the course, though I might misunderstand it). I think if it's proved that the evaluation of an expression is deterministic, say x[0] is always 0 , then you can't say that expression is of UB, can you?

Comment: @Yang: The machine code generated by a particular execution of a particular compiler is often (but not always) deterministic even when the source code invokes UB.  That doesn't make the expression well-defined, though, since when you recompile you may get different results.

Comment: @BenVoigt Thanks a lot Ben. I've voted your comment for being explicit. I might take a look at codes in assembly into which language MS compiler interprets z=std::move(x) to see if evaluation is deterministic at that level of logics. My experiments (around dozen times of recompile) before posting this question showed that it was deterministic, at least emperically.